# Android SQLite: cursor.getcount() always return greater than 0

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I am working on basic register and login activity, I have created two activities Login and Register. The register activity is working properly(i guess) but in Login activity it always allows user to successful login even if enter wrong email and password.

**myDbAdapter**

```
public class myDbAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="UserManager";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="UserData";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";


    public myDbAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        System.out.println("Table created here");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }
    //Add register data inside table
public void addDetails(String em,String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(EMAIL,em);
values.put(PASSWORD,em);

db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
db.close();

}

    public boolean checkUser(String e1, String p1) {

        String[] columns = {
                KEY_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {e1, p1};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Login**

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    myDbAdapter ob =new myDbAdapter(this);
    String k,k1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        EditText ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lee);
        EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lep);
        Button bn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonL);
        k=ed.getText().toString();
        k1=ed1.getText().toString();
        bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ob.checkUser(k,k1))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });



    }
}
```

**Register**

```
public class Register extends Activity{
    myDbAdapter ob =new myDbAdapter(this);
    String s,s1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        EditText edm= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editE);
        EditText edp= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editP);
        s=edm.getText().toString();
        s1=edp.getText().toString();
        Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RegiB);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ob.addDetails(s,s1);
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In Login activity the Toast text is always **Login Successfully**. I am trying to find if an email and password already exist in table using **checkuser** function which always **returns true** is that `cursor.getcount()>0`always 
 Any help?

Comment: problem is here `values.put(PASSWORD,em);` it should be `values.put(PASSWORD,pass);`

Comment: @AbhishekSingh thanks for pointing out but it doesnt seem to the problem in login , it should cause login failed but am getting login successfully

Comment: Also store values in `k,k1` and `s,s1` on button click. you are storing blanck and query with blank

Comment: your comment was much useful than answer @AbhishekSingh , solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code with below codes. You are storing blank and query with blank thats why you are getting `columnCount()>0`

**Login**

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    myDbAdapter ob =new myDbAdapter(this);
    String k,k1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        EditText ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lee);
        EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lep);
        Button bn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonL);

        bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                k=ed.getText().toString();
                k1=ed1.getText().toString();
                if(ob.checkUser(k,k1))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Register**

```
public class Register extends Activity{
    myDbAdapter ob =new myDbAdapter(this);
    String s,s1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        EditText edm= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editE);
        EditText edp= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editP);
        Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RegiB);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                s=edm.getText().toString();
                s1=edp.getText().toString();
                ob.addDetails(s,s1);
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use [`cursor.moveToFirst()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) to find whether the cursor is empty alongside with `cursor.getCount()` for the sake of reliability.

```
if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    // doSomething
} else {
    // doOtherThing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

**Login Part**

```
EditText ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lee);
        EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lep);
        Button bn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonL);

        bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             k=ed.getText().toString();
             k1=ed1.getText().toString();
                if(ob.checkUser(k,k1))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

**Register Part**

```
        Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RegiB);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           s=edm.getText().toString();
           s1=edp.getText().toString();
                ob.addDetails(s,s1);
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Read text from EditText onClick  not while initializing as it will be empty always

**Register**

```
     Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RegiB);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              s=edm.getText().toString();
             s1=edp.getText().toString();
                ob.addDetails(s,s1);
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Login**

```
   bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         k=ed.getText().toString();
         k1=ed1.getText().toString();
            if(ob.checkUser(k,k1))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if its empty than how the cursor is returning its count greater than 0 always?

Comment: rows are not empty, email and password values inside row are empty

Comment: i got you.. thanx